# Read a Bash variable assignment from other file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have this test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Read a variable" 
#open file
exec 6<test.txt
read EXAMPLE <&6
#close file again
exec 6<&-
echo $EXAMPLE
```

The file `test.txt` has only one line:

```
EXAMPLE=1
```

The output is:

```
bash-3.2$ ./Read_Variables.sh
Read the variable
EXAMPLE=1
```

I need just to use the value of `$EXAMPLE`, in this case `1`. So how can I avoid getting the `EXAMPLE=` part in the output?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the file containing your variables is using bash syntax throughout (e.g. X=Y), another option is to use `source`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Read a variable" 
source test.txt
echo $EXAMPLE
```

Comment: Think this is the easiest way to do it. Although @HermanTorjussen  your method worked and I dind't know you could read the line as an array, it will definitely be useful later. THANKS!

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to sourcing the entire file, you can try the following:

```
while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ EXAMPLE= ]] && declare "$line" && break
done < test.txt
```

which will scan the file until it finds the first line that looks like an assignment to `EXAMPLE`, then use the `declare` builtin to perform the assignment. It's probably a little slower, but it's more selective about what is actually executed.

Comment: This treats quotes as literals: `declare 'foo=""' && [[ "$foo" == '""' ]]`

Answer (score 5):

I think the most proper way to do this is by sourcing the file which contains the variable (if it has bash syntax), but if I were to do that, I'd source it in a subshell, so that if there are ever other variables declared there, they won't override any important variables in current shell:

```
(. test.txt && echo $EXAMPLE)
```

Comment: Simple and elegant!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Subshell is always safer and makes more sense unless you need to use the entire file for other reasons. `WORKING_VARIABLE=$(source /path/script.sh; echo $FILE_VARIABLE)` ... see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1302177/935172

Answer (score 0):

You could read the line in as an array (notice the `-a` option) which can then be indexed into:

```
# ...
IFS='=' read -a EXAMPLE <&6
echo ${EXAMPLE[0]} # EXAMPLE
echo ${EXAMPLE[1]} # 1
# ...
```

This call to `read` splits the input line on the `IFS` and puts the remaining parts into an indexed array.
See `help read` for more information about `read` options and behaviour.
You could also manipulate the `EXAMPLE` variable directly:

```
# ...
read EXAMPLE <&6
echo ${EXAMPLE##*=} # 1
# ...
```

If all you need is to "import" other Bash declarations from a file you should just use:

```
source file
```